# using Serilog Asp.net core dotnet 5 preview 7

Tags: asp.net-core, logging, serilog, .net-5

Serilog community.
Firstly, thank you for the great library!

I am trying out Asp.Net on Net 5 Preview 7 at the time of writing this question. I have created 2 web API projects one targeting [netcoreapp3.1] and another targeting [net5].

Below is my bootstrapping code, it is identical for both APIs

```
using System.Diagnostics;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Serilog;
using Serilog.Formatting.Elasticsearch;

namespace WebApplication1
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Activity.DefaultIdFormat = ActivityIdFormat.W3C;
            Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
                .MinimumLevel.Debug()
                .Enrich.FromLogContext()
                .WriteTo.Console(new ExceptionAsObjectJsonFormatter(renderMessage: true))
                .CreateLogger();
            CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
        }

        public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseSerilog()
                .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
                {
                    webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
                });
    }
}
```

The problem is when I am looking at logs, I no longer see **TraceId and SpanId** for the API targeting [net5] with the DotNet 5 preview 7 SDK.

I also tested using the vanilla Logger and there was no issue there. Do I have to configure something, did I just miss something or is the DotNet 5 Preview SDK not fully supported yet?

Thanks for any info, much appreciated.

PS: Serilog Nuget packages used

```
<PackageReference Include="Serilog.AspNetCore" Version="3.4.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Serilog.Formatting.Elasticsearch" Version="8.2.0" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems there was a change for logging in DotNet 5. Have a look at the GitHub issue linked here for the details,

[serilog-aspnetcore github issue](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-aspnetcore/issues/207)